# 成语 versus 俗语 versus 谚语, what is the difference?

Tags: proverb, saying

I know the rough difference between a 成语 (4-character proverb)and a 俗语 (8-character or so saying), but what is a 谚语, and how does it differ from these?

I am also interested in 熟语。 How does this differ from these three?

Comment: You might mean `成语`?

Comment: I have updated my post to take a fourth word into account. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

成語 and 諺語 are well established common expressions , well known by the whole population. 俗語 is more often, limited to regional use.

- 成語 mostly refer to Chinese idiom.
- 諺語 can be from different countries.
- Chinese 成語 are uniformly four characters phrases.
- For 俗語 and 諺語,  number of character are flexible, some come in two parts.

Examples:

> 俗語 : "有便宜唔好使頸" (Cantonese) : "If there's benefit to be have, don't be stubborn."
>
> 諺語: "神要毀滅某人，必先使其瘋狂" (western): " "Those whom the gods wish to destroy they first make mad."

- 諺語 (proverb) include  "common sense" and "words of wisdom". from known or unknown origins.
- 俗語 (folk saying) include "situation description", "common sense" and "words of wisdom".
- 成語 (idiom) include  "situation description" , "common sense", and "words of wisdom".  Mostly came from known historical references, like poems, classical literature or famous quotes by historic figures .

Edit:

**熟语** (Well known phrases) include:

惯用语(common phrase), usually contain three characters, for example: "打秋風"，"拍馬屁" , 成語, 諺語, 俗語, 歇后语(two-part allegorical saying), for example: "和尚打傘，無法無天" and 格言(motto), usually from famous people, for example: "We have nothing to fear but fear itself." by Franklin D. Roosevelt.

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive answer. I would be happy to invite your post, if you could do me the favor of including your description of 熟语. This is from the front of a book.

Comment: ＂front of a  book"? cover/封面? title page/书名页／扉页? There exists ＂汉语熟语小词典＂containing 成语、惯用语 and **歇后语**  bkrs：[a two-part allegorical saying; sequel]通常只说前一部分, 后一部分不言而喻 e。g。十五个吊桶（打水）──七上八下

Comment: famous example of 谚语：闰七不闰八，闰八过刀杀 （see web) mentioned in 《饥饿的女儿》，作者：虹影

author writes 我正是能随口念叨这些谚语的孩子中的一个

Comment: 格言 bkrs：（含有教育意义的成语） maxim; motto; aphorism; an established maxim:e。g。“规范的调查是犯罪学的道德基础。”"Uniform codes of investigation are the moral foundation of criminology." http://www.baiyun.net/detective/wccs07.html

Comment: 语录 quotation，e。g。 **毛主席语录**  e。g。教育必须为无产阶级政治服务，必须同生产劳动相结合。为什么语言要学，并且要用很大的气力去学呢？因为语言这东西，不是随便可以学好的，非下苦动不可。